# Proof that every singleton is Borel-measurable

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $a \in \mathbb R$, Is it enough to say that $ {a} = (]-\infty, a [  \cup ]a, \infty[)^{c}$ which is the complementary of the union of two open sets so $a$ belongs to the Borel sigma algebra ?

Comment: Yes. Actually any closed set is also  a Borel set because sigma albebra's are closed under complementation and open sets are Borel sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your guess is right. Notation only: the set you wrote equals $\{a\}$, not $a$.

For sake of completeness, this statement usually gets proved stating that $\{a\} = \cap_{n=1}^\infty(a-\frac{1}{n},a+\frac{1}{n})$. Down the road you might find this useful.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I can easily see that singletons are Borel if the topological space is induced by a metric. What if it is not? I'm trying to think of a way to create nested balls that converges to a point, but it seems hard without a metric.